# Gas required exceeds allowance(0)

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, gas, ethers.js, gas-limit

I've seen a lot of posts on this error, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my contract and why this is happening. I have my contract code below:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Send {
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendToOwner() public payable {}

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function sendToAddress(address payable _to) public payable {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        (bool sent, ) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

and this is where it's called in ethers:

```
async function main(_receiverAddress, _ethAmount) {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL); //using Alchemy as provider and Goerli as testnet
  await newAccount();
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./wallet_contracts_Send_sol_Send.abi", "utf8");
  const bin = fs.readFileSync("./wallet_contracts_Send_sol_Send.bin", "utf8");
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bin, wallet);
  console.log("deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); //never gets past here
  await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  const txResp = await contract.sendToAddress(_receiverAddress, {
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(_ethAmount),
  });
  await txResp.wait(1);
}
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

This is part of the error:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","error":{"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":49,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"gas required exceeds allowance (0)\"}}","error":{"code":-32000},
```

I understand it says that it may require manual gas limit, but would like to see if there's a way I can avoid doing that. I wanted to have a way to connect with Goerli and load the wallet automatically using the sendToOwner function, but I can't figure out how that would work, and it doesn't get past the deploy() function anyway. Any help is appreciated!